# Wordpress Plugin/widget how change the render code?

Tags: wordpress

This is my first time working with plugins and widgets for Wordpress. My plugin/widget is working fine, but why are "widgets" in the sidebar inside `<li>`?

How can I render the widget in other tags?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try modify function.php file and insert it :

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
        'after_title' => '</div>',
    ));
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget